# Getting the aggregation result from the single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, relational-database

In the following, I am querying the same table 2 times. The second query is a nested query inside `left join` but queries the same table. The only difference is the addition of the aggregation function `count`, the result of which is used by the outer query.  Is there a better way to approach this?

```
    select sm.student_id, sm.marks, smarks.d as d_marks from student_marks as sm 
left join(
    select m.student_id, count(distinct m.marks) as d from student_marks as m group by m.student_id
    ) as smarks on smarks.student_id = sm.student_id;
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query without using a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an alternative approach which is using [windowed functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). There's no way of doing `COUNT(DISTINCT` in a windowed function, but you can do this using [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) twice, once sorting by what you want a distinct count of ascending, and once descending, adding these together then taking one away:

```
SELECT sm.student_id, 
       sm.marks, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sm.student_id ORDER BY sm.marks DESC) + 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY  sm.student_id ORDER BY sm.marks ASC) - 1 AS d_marks 
FROM   student_marks AS sm
```

N.B. this is not guaranteed to perform any better just because you are referencing a table one fewer times.

To explain the `DENSE_RANK()` trick, consider a simple data set:

| marks | dense_rank ASC | dense_rank DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

The two ranks added together will always be one more than the total number of items in the set (i.e. 1+3, 2+2, and 3+1 all equal 4), so we just need to take one off the result and this gives us our distinct count of items in the set without actually using `COUNT(DISTINCT` which isn't allowed ([as noted in the restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-restrictions.html))

---

**ADENDUM**

If `marks` is nullable (which I had assumed it would not be) and you don't want null rows included in the count, then as noted in the comments this wouldn't quite work as it is, you'd need to remove any null rows from the total, which can be done using:

```
- MAX(CASE WHEN sm.marks IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY sm.student_id)
```

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` ranks also any existing nulls which are not counted by `COUNT(DISTINCT m.marks)`. So this is not equivalent to `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` if the column is nullable.